# Else if statement causes error whereas using only if statements doesn't

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
function guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts){
  var attempts = attempts || 0
  return graph.postAsync(endpointId + '/feed', wallPost)
  .then(function(response){
    return response
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    if(error.message != errorMessage){
      return Promise.reject(error.message)
    }
    console.log('Retry attempt #: ' + attempts)
    if(attempts == 5){
      return Promise.reject('Too many errors')
    }
    // console.log(error)
    return Promise.delay(5000).then(function(){      
      return guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts + 1)
    })
  });
}
```

Everything works fine.

If I change the second if to an else if:

```
function guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts){
  var attempts = attempts || 0
  return graph.postAsync(endpointId + '/feed', wallPost)
  .then(function(response){
    return response
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    if(error.message != errorMessage){
      return Promise.reject(error.message)
    }
    console.log('Retry attempt #: ' + attempts)
    else if(attempts == 5){ //BLOWS UP
      return Promise.reject('Too many errors')
    }
    // console.log(error)
    return Promise.delay(5000).then(function(){      
      return guaranteedPost(endpointId, wallPost, attempts + 1)
    })
  });
}
```

This blows up my code with a syntax error:

```
    else if(attempts == 5){
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
```

Why is this happening? I am using else if statements all over my code and I receive no errors. Nothing I can seem to do in testing will allow me to get around this error.

Comment: because there is a `console` between the `if` and the `else if`.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't really call this is a simple typographical error, considering the error was produced by a feature of Javascript, and not a typo for example. I even explicitly state that it is working with only an if statement, but not with an else if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have

```
    console.log('Retry attempt #: ' + attempts)
```

before `else` keyword. `else` keyword is required to be immediately after `if` block.

Comment: I would have never guessed that was the cause, and the stack trace sure wasn't helping. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of this line from your code before **else** block

```
console.log('Retry attempt #: ' + attempts)
```